# When Android kills your app's process, does it include all the processes belonging to the app?

Tags: android, process

It is well known that can Android can kill the app's process at any time (mostly only when the app is in the background).

What about running Services that are running in a separate process with the `android:process` XML tag? Could the system remove only one of the processes or are they always both killed at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When Android kills an app's process, it will typically kill the entire app and all the processes belonging to it. This is done to free up system resources and improve overall device performance. However, there may be some cases where only a portion of the app's processes are killed, depending on the specific circumstances. For example, if the app is running in the background and is not actively being used, Android may choose to kill only some of its processes.